# How can you support multiple devices with expansions?

Tags: android

I'm working on a android app that will display gemstones. Putting thumbnails in drawable-XXSIZE is not a problem, but how can I continue this with expansion files?

If I create folders such as: drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi etc. and put everything in a zip (I can only have 2 expansion files) will I be able to download only what I need? (I'm guessing no...)

So how can I make sure the tablet user will get big image for full screen such as 1920px (worst case scenario) and for mobile phone alot smaller.
What is the best approach for this kind of applications?

Should I just put it on my own server and make my own image management?

I would like to just put it in a bundle and the end user have an app that is as small as possible without loosing quality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution to this. I just have to build functionality. Previous answer it has nothing to do with my question

Answer (score 0):

You need to try sdp library for this

https://github.com/intuit/sdp

After this your problem is solved and also try vactor images so you do not need different image size in all folder like mdpi or ldpi or xxhdp ,need to store single vactor image in drawable folder.

Comment: as I said these are gemstones (real images). so there is no way I can convert all of them into vectors and keep the same quality and cpu performance

Comment: Also from what I see the library is just using a different scale, I don't see how will it download only the images that it needs.

Comment: For real images you just need to add image compressor that reduse the image size bit not the quality and use glide or piccaso to download it.

Comment: Using glide you never lose the quality and it help to maintain the cashe

Comment: No, the valid response for now is my own. Build custom functionality that will allow users to download the appropiate size.